# Azure DevOps AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task overrideParameters array

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-yaml

This *should* be easy :)

Can anyone assist with the syntax required for the *AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3* task to assign a value in *overrideParameters* where the ARM template parameters file is expecting an array?

Example:

The ARM template parameters file expects an array:

```
"my-ssis-ir_publicIPs": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                "/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/my-01-ssisir-pip",
                "/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/my-02-ssisir-pip"
            ]
        },
```

AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 code task - showing the attempt to use override parameters  to provide override values for my-ssis-ir_publicIPs with hard-coded values representing two public ips as an array:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.azureResourceManagerConnection }}
    subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
    resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}
    location: '${{ parameters.location }}'
    csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{parameters.squadName}}/$(Build.Repository.Name)/${{parameters.buildId}}/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{parameters.squadName}}/$(Build.Repository.Name)/${{parameters.buildId}}/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters:
          -my-ssis-ir_publicIPs ['/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/my-01-ssisir-pip','/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/my-02-ssisir-pip']
```

Most of my efforts result in errors indicating that a string is being passed into the parameter, where an Array is expected.

I have tried a number of options such as - setting parameters in the yml file

```
parameters:
 - name: my-ssis-ir_publicIPs
   type: object
   default:
    - '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/my-01-ssisir-pip'
    - '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/my-02-ssisir-pip'
```

And then have tried to assign the parameter:

```
overrideParameters:
              -my-ssis-ir_publicIPs ${{ convertToJson(parameters.my-ssis-ir_publicIPs) }}
```

Obviously, I will need to be using parameters, passed into the YAML file, but am first trying to get this to work by learning the syntax at the point the override is being applied.

Comment: This stuff is hard because the doco isn't clear and the error messages unhelpful. Very frustrating when you have to fall back to simply googling and guessing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works, is you have arm template JSON and arm template parameters JSON.

So you have a parameter to `overrideParameters` that will pass it to arm template parameters.

so let's take an example, here we have `managementgroup.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/managementGroupDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "NameId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "DisplayName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ParentId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Location": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('NameId')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "scope": "/",
      "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
      "properties": {
        "details": {
          "parent": {
            "id": "[tenantResourceId('Microsoft.Management/managementGroups', parameters('ParentId'))]"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('DisplayName')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "output": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('NameId')]"
    }
  }
}
```

And here we have `managementgroup.parameters.json` that takes 3 parameters:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "NameId": {
      "value": {}
    },
    "DisplayName": {
      "value": {}
    },
    "ParentId": {
      "value": {}
    },
    "Location": {
      "value": "westeurope"
    }
  }
}
```

Now lets as you can see we pass parameters to AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment:

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: "Creating/Updating ${{ parameters.DisplayName }}"
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: "Management Group"
      azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.ServiceConnection }}
      location: "West Europe"
      csmFile: "${{ parameters.ArmBasePath }}/managementgroup.json"
      csmParametersFile: "${{ parameters.ArmBasePath }}/managementgroup.parameters.json"
      overrideParameters: "-NameId ${{ parameters.NameId }} -DisplayName ${{ parameters.DisplayName }} -ParentId ${{ parameters.ParentId }}"
      deploymentMode: "Incremental"
      deploymentOutputs: armOutputs
```

In this case I pass parameters from yaml.

```
parameters:
  - name: ParentId
    type: string
  - name: NameId
    type: string
  - name: DisplayName
    type: string
  - name: ServiceConnection
    type: string
  - name: ArmBasePath
    type: string
```

Now if you need to run this multiple times, for instance, 2 calls one for network 1 and a second call for network 2, you just create a template and call it as many times as possible. I use this example to create multiple management groups. I provided this example, you can change it to fit it your question.

Comment: Maytham - Thanks for your response. Understand what you have; and all makes sense. In my case however, the template and params file are auto-generated through Azure Data Factory. I found the syntax that worked... in my answer below

Comment: Nice  that is cool

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that worked for me was to pass in the two IPs as separate parameters as follow:

```
-my-ssis-ir_publicIPs ["${{parameters.ssisir_publicIp1}}","${{parameters.ssisir_publicIp2}}"]
```

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)